# string manipulation to remove the name of files

Tags: r, string

I have a list of strings

```
/temp/123/afedcgid/abc.csv
/temp/123/4388dkfa/abc1.csv
/temp/123/4388dkfa/ab1.csv
```

I want to remove name of the file from the strings
The results desired are

```
/temp/123/afedcgid
/temp/123/4388dkfa
/temp/123/4388dkfa
```

How can i do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below,

```
sub("/[^/]*$", "", x)
```

It removes all the chars from the last `/` symbol.

**OR**

```
> x <- "/temp/123/afedcgid/abc.csv"
> sub("(.*)/.*", "\\1", x)
[1] "/temp/123/afedcgid"
```

captures all the chars from the start upto the last `/` symbol (excluding /). Then the following chars are matched by `.*`. Replacing the matched chars with chars inside group 1 will give you the desired output.

**Example:**

```
> x <- "/temp/123/afedcgid/abc.csv"
> sub("/[^/]*$", "", x)
[1] "/temp/123/afedcgid"
```

**OR**

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr(".+(?=/)", x, perl=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex to catch character you want to replace

```
\/\w+\.\w+$
```

try this demo

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xX7jE0/1)

```
files <- c("/temp/123/afedcgid/abc.csv" , 
"/temp/123/4388dkfa/abc1.csv" , "/temp/123/4388dkfa/ab1.csv")

sub("\\/\\w+\\.\\w+$" , "" , files)
```

as you may know you need to `\\` for escaping sequences in `R`